# How to simply activate redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-cache

I thought that for the design of a mvc project in spring boot it was possible to add later and simply redis to the project.

I have been trying for a few days to add redis to my project and I am having difficulties.

I added this in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I added this in main

@Cacheable

and I have this error message:

```
Spring Data Redis - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface *. If you want this repository to be a Redis repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash (preferred), or consider extending one of the following types with your repository: org.springframework.data.keyvalue.repository.KeyValueRepository.
```

then following the explanation on stackoverflow I added:

```
#spring.data.redis.repositories.type=none
#spring.data.ldap.repositories.enabled=false
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

but I have this message:

```
Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost/<unresolved>:6379
```

So yes it can't connect but I thought that by adding @Cacheable everything would be configured automatically ?!

I am clearly lost I thought it was that simple!

Do you have a good link so that I can set up redis on my project? thank you

thank you so much

Comment: Redis server runs in a separate process from the Spring Boot one, it is not embedded. You need to spin up a Redis server. The easiest way IMHO is starting redis inside a container. https://hub.docker.com/_/redis

Comment: Ha ok I didn't understand that. I'll watch thank you. But are you used to spring boot MVC? I don't understand, my home page, with a simple query count takes 1.1 seconds in production to respond